# Can we say "Electronic dictionaries are useful IN looking up words?

Tags: grammaticality

One of the teachers at my school asked me this question. I believe the answer is NO. We can use FOR or WHEN but I don't believe IN is workable. Am I right and why?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? If so, why doesn't, for example, "During the act or process of: *tripped in racing for the bus*" (*American Heritage*) cover the case you've exampled?

Comment: JEL Point well taken. To me however, this sounds totally unnatural. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Does this sound natural to you: "Electronic dictionaries are useful IN  [regards to the practice of] looking up words?"  Sometimes omitted words are implied.  Still if you're willing to type a whole extra letter, consider replacing *in* with *for*

Comment: If the sense of the phrase is "useful in the process of looking up words," the shortened form "useful in looking up words" seems perfectly reasonable; if the sense of the phrase is "useful for the purpose of looking up words," the shortened form "useful for looking up words" seems equally reasonable. Basically, the intention of the speaker or writer in formulating the wording goes a long way toward justifying the shortened form that the person may be using.